# One of the the two events must occur. If the chance of $A$ is $2/3$ of that of $B$, then odds in favour of $B$ are:

Tags: probability

I am just stumped by this question. I don’t know how to find the union of the two events. Please help and don’t remove the question for lack of trying on my part.

Comment: If *exactly* (actually I miss this word) one of the events $A,B$ *must* occur then $B$ must be the complement of $A$. This enables you to find $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.

Comment: You are right, this the way to get to the right answer as people have replied below

Answer (score 0):

Let probability of occurrence of $B$ is $P(B) =p$ 
Hence, $P(A) =2p/3$ 
Since one of these must occur, we have $ p+2p/3=1\implies p=3/5$ 
Odds in favor of $B$=( favourable conditions for B) /(non favourable conditions for B) $=3/(5-3)=3/2$

Comment: Thanks for the right answer

Answer (score 0):

You have $P(A)=\frac{2}{3}\cdot{}P(B)$, and since one of the events must occur, you also have $P(A)+P(B)=1$.

Substituting information from the first equation into the second, we have $\frac{2}{3}\cdot{}P(B)+P(B)=1$, or $\frac{5}{3}\cdot{}P(B)=1$

Thus $P(B)=\frac{3}{5}$ and therefore $P(A)=\frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: Thanks for the right answer